# Why does the trailing edge have a more pronounced taper than the leading edge on the Cessna 172?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-performance, wing, control-surfaces, cessna-172

[image: Cessna 172 3-view diagram]

Why does the Cessna 172 have a more pronounced taper on the trailing edge as opposed to the leading edge?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's just the natural taper you get when the spar is straight in plan view, and the spar depth and airfoil is shrinking as it gets to the tip.[image].

The chord is constant out to the strut attachment so the LE and TE is parallel. As the airfoil gets thinner outboard of that, if you keep the same profile it shortens chordwise as it gets thinner. Since the taper's neutral axis, the spar, is near the front at 15 or 20% of chord, the apparent taper in plan view seems more extreme at the TE.

Comment: Maybe you can add [this cutaway](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/0a/5a/83/0a5a836fae004fd3cf6a906b4db0620a.jpg) to your answer to help visualise your point

Comment: @sophit Great idea thanks.

Comment: It could be argued that there is nothing "natural" about this. It is an engineering decision on how to balance conflicting goals, including performance in various flight regimes and cost of manufacture as examples of two conflicting goals (designing for better performance would cost more to produce).

Comment: "Natural" simply means the normal geometric result of tapering thickness with the same airfoil profile and a neutral axis forward. You are reading way too much into it.

Answer (score 3):

You know, I never thought of it as a "natural" taper, but something the Wright Brothers found out in their early (low subsonic) wind tunnel experiments was that taking a little off the trailing edge corners of the "Hershey Bar" wing does save a little in drag.

Some like a [rounded](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_P-47_Thunderbolt) trailing edge, but a simple taper is easier to manufacture.

Comment: The balance between "empirism, performance, cost of manufacturing" behind the fact that all medium passenger jets are boringly equal.
If you excel in the first and third parameters, your name is Boeing or Airbus. 
In the second and third, your name is Lockheed Martin or Mikoyan-Gurevich
If you excel in the first and second: Hi Burt Rutan, how are you?